# What do the symbols on the top of The Witcher 2's screen mean?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Ok, so I get that these are active effects that you are currently under, and the timer is straightforward and what not, but the symbol itself is nigh meaningless, and I don't know what effects I'm under...

I've installed the game vanilla through GOG, and I let the installer patch itself to 3.2 and I'm aware of an "Official UI Mod" that comes with patch 3.2, I've left it on as the default setting...

So is there like a guide or something which helps disambiguate this?

[image]

Comment: try hovering over it with your mouse, it should show the effect if I remember correctly.

Comment: Nope, doesn't... You only get the cursor when you bring up the quick menu with Ctrl, and hovering over the icons doesn't have a tooltip or anything...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like the symbol for the "[Circle of Vigor](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Circle_of_Power)" - a hexagon.  It boosts your vitality regeneration for 5 minutes.

Likely you visited the Circle of Vigor in the forest outside Flotsam.  The Circles all have unusual icons, but potion/oil effects typically look like the potion or oil that grants them.

I couldn't find any particular status screen that lists your effects and the symbol associated with them, sadly.

Comment: I mean, so these symbols are there, but they're not described anywhere at all? Inside or outside the game?

Comment: @Abhishek, not really, no.  The wiki page I linked describes the symbols associated with the Circles, and the oils/potions are the same symbols they are in your inventory.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this thread is long dead but if anyone gets here from a search, like I did:

You can see the names of active potions by Meditating and going to Drink Potions. Active potions will already be placed in the circles on the right and you can see their names by hovering your pointer over them (on the PC, don't know how this works on consoles).

Comment: Thanks for the update... I don't have access to the game for now, so can't check/verify... But I'm sure some patch since the games initial release would have made this easier at some point...